# How to smooth the curve with scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

I want to smooth y keeping the spike around x=15 with 1D spline, but splrep gives me the original curve back instead of a smoothing curve

I have 1D data

```
    y=[0.0,
 5.2052869332441025,
 5.0601305002509624,
 4.4754224527354864,
 4.098745189894596,
 3.8030115442529695,
 3.9431487368244937,
 3.9593776141877197,
 3.7963526852936256,
 3.075221683118621,
 2.8724109084825162,
 2.866220511962523,
 2.977279571691484,
 3.0507612514639453,
 5.463175506106743,
 3.381127656014723,
 3.501990965367241,
 3.0149573364564164,
 2.5853772795716914,
 2.7330767943784506,
 2.5419775807261167,
 2.512698678266689,
 2.299916345992973,
 2.3513468295131337,
 2.2943951815291954,
 2.1383302660197425,
 2.039049690480174,
 2.0590262673582065,
 1.763627237744688,
 1.6120461770118788,
 1.3718587920361385,
 1.3859795884222854,
 1.4755228375439184,
 1.4741174502258658,
 1.341174502258658,
 1.251095867492053,
 1.2914505604818471,
 1.171791868830517,
 1.183369583403045,
 1.2024092354023759,
 1.1481345156432994,
 1.0947632591601137,
 0.9685795549606826,
 0.9010540404885394,
 0.8684624393508449,
 0.9203948469131671,
 0.9727622553120294,
 0.9937426802743852,
 0.8627070436673917,
 0.8518989459595114,
 0.8220511962523005,
 0.763024928894094,
 0.8072946294127489,
 0.8351012213485026,
 0.8100384808432324,
 0.7550945290279404,
 0.763761084155931,
 0.7193240756232223,
 0.654642797389995,
 0.6931571022251966,
 0.7534883720930232,
 0.7887234398527689,
 0.8088338631420445,
 0.7992973063409737,
 0.6131838715074452,
 0.6243600468462439,
 0.6293458256650494,
 0.675723607160783,
 0.6525012548101055,
 0.6767943784507278,
 0.5731972561485695,
 0.5542579889576711,
 0.5267190898444035,
 0.5764430316212147,
 0.6174000334616028,
 0.5661368579554961,
 0.5512464447047014,
 0.5003513468295131,
 0.4946294127488707,
 0.47846745859126655,
 0.42569851095867495,
 0.445139702191735,
 0.3626568512631755,
 0.3501756734147566,
 0.36406223858122805,
 0.37463610506943285,
 0.4220177346494897,
 0.39943115275221686,
 0.37416764263008195,
 0.3197590764597624,
 0.3206960013384641,
 0.3014890413250795,
 0.30654174334950646,
 0.29887903630583906,
 0.31075790530366404,
 0.2676593608833863,
 0.23704199431152753,
 0.2364062238581228,
 0.22820813116948302,
 0.22255312029446211,
 0.2174000334616028,
 0.21244771624560815,
 0.2050192404216162,
 0.20324577547264513,
 0.20940271038982766,
 0.25347164129161787,
 0.1964530701020579,
 0.21512464447047014,
 0.23463275890915175,
 0.21559310690982098,
 0.193173833026602,
 0.1790195750376443,
 0.19337460264346662,
 0.22462773966873012,
 0.1699514806759244,
 0.16576878032457754,
 0.16941609503095198,
 0.14887067090513637,
 0.13652333946796052,
 0.14214488874017064,
 0.1335117952149908,
 0.13749372594947298,
 0.1375941107579053,
 0.14007026936590264,
 0.1288940940271039,
 0.13545256817801574,
 0.13237410071942446,
 0.1284925547933746,
 0.1456248954324912,
 0.12815793876526685,
 0.13719257152417602,
 0.16309185209971558,
 0.12514639451229714,
 0.12996486531704868,
 0.12725447548937593,
 0.11581060732809101,
 0.12497908649824327,
 0.12270369750711059,
 0.11835368914170989,
 0.1259829345825665,
 0.1470972059561653,
 0.15097875188221516,
 0.16255646645474317,
 0.12919524845240088,
 0.11326752551447214,
 0.11658022419273883,
 0.00023423121967542247]
 x=list(range(len(y)))
```

Comment: AFAIK, splines interpolate, but they do not smooth

Comment: Looks like you need polynomial regression, not interpolation.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible, the data looks like a downsampled histogram of a 2d detector showing some high energy peak, the peak you want to preserve is the sharpest peak of your data, hence not possible. In the real data you can try medfilt from scipy.signal or fft filtering but in this